# Adding documents to Firestore using a for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, google-cloud-firestore

I am building an application which logs financial transactions. I want do add similar transactions with one action, therefor I use a for loop to add the transactions to the Cloud `Firestore` database. The only parameter that changes is the date of the transaction.

My code cycles trough the for loop, but all instances get added to `Firestore`, before the date is changed, later in the for loop.

I understand that this is because of the asynchronous aspect of Cloud `Firestore`, but I can't figure out how to get this to work.

I placed the code that changes the date in different spots in the for loop, but the result stays the same.

```
let date = transaction.date;

let freqNmbr = document.getElementById('newTransactionFreqNmbr').value;

for (i = 0; i < freqNmbr; i++) {


db.collection(auth.currentUser.uid).doc("db").collection("transactions").add({
                    amount: transaction.amount,
                    date: date,
                    status: transaction.status,
                    account: transaction.account,
                    description: transaction.description,
                    freqNmbr: transaction.freqNmbr,
                    freqType: transaction.freqType
                })
                    .then(function (docRef) {
                        console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);

                        date = new Date(date);

                        if (transaction.freqType == "dag") {
                            date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
                        } else if (transaction.freqType == "week") {
                            date.setDate(date.getDate() + 7);
                        } else if (transaction.freqType == "maand") {
                            date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 1);
                        } else {
                            date.setFullYear(date.getFullYear() + 1);
                        }

                        let yy = date.getFullYear();
                        let mm = '' + (date.getMonth() + 1);
                        let dd = '' + date.getDate();

                        if (mm.length < 2) mm = '0' + mm;
                        if (dd.length < 2) dd = '0' + dd;

                        date = yy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
                    })
                    .catch(function (error) {
                        console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
                    });

            }
```

Comment: Have you looked into batched writes: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions?

Comment: I checked that page yesterday, but it didn't click right away. Looking at it with a fresh mind it makes way more sense. Will look in to it today and report back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Batched write to fix this.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions

Comment: Maybe you'd also accept the answer, so the question doesn't show up as unanswered in search.